# Метод таймер C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

У меня есть переменная speed = 5.0F
Мне нужно написать метод (который я потом буду вызывать), который на определенное время меняет значение переменной, но после окончания времени, возвращает её значение обратно. Есть наброски

```
public void Wait(int min)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMinutes < min)
    {
                
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep() не подходит вместо бесконечного цикла?

Comment: `_= Task.Run(async () => { speed =1; await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); speed = 5; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен метод типа "запустил и забыл", то можно так

```
public async void Wait(float delaySpeed, int milliseconds)
{
    float tmp = speed;
    speed = delaySpeed;
    await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
    speed = tmp;
}
```

```cs
Wait(1.0f, 5000);
```

Если конечно это Unity, то там есть свои методы решения данной задачи.